# v-model support for a component that is built on top of another component

Tags: vue.js

I am trying to support `v-model` two-way binding for my own component (`my-component`) that is built on top of another [external lib](https://vue-multiselect.js.org/) component (`multiselect`).

For example, I have

```
Vue.component('my-component', {
    props: ['value'],
    delimiters: ['[[', ']]'],
    components: {
        Multiselect: window.VueMultiselect.default
    },
    data() {
        return {
           
        }
    },
    methods: {
        
    },
    template: `<multiselect
                    v-model="value">
                </multiselect>`
})
```

So, now I want to have something like this:

```
<div id='#vue-wrapper'>
     <async-select :value="foo"></async-select>
</div>


new Vue({
    el: '#vue-wrapper',
    components: { VueMyComponent: "async-select" },
    data: {
       foo: null
    },
    watch: {
       foo(){
         console.log('Wow, foo has changed. Now foo =', this.foo);
       }
    },
```

Is that possible? I want to bind the variable foo (that is passed as a prop to `my-component`) to v-model of `multiselect`

I have created a [JSFIddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7tukqxpb/1/) to illustrate that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use an intermediate local variable:

```js
props: ['value'],
data: () => ({localValue: this.value}),
template: `<multiselect v-model="localValue" />`,
watch:
{
  localValue(newVal, oldVal)
  {
    if (JSON.stringify(newVal) !== JSON.stringify(oldVal)) this.$emit('input', newVal)
  },
  value(newVal, oldVal)
  {
    if (JSON.stringify(newVal) !== JSON.stringify(oldVal)) this.localValue = newVal
  }
}
```

Comment: See the updated question. I have added a Fiddle for you

Comment: It works just fine if you replace `:value="value"` with `v-model="value"` in your Fiddle.